# How I can ask a specify Name Server to have the IP of a domain

Tags: hosting, dns, web-hosting

For example, I have a domain name example.com hosted at some host free, and now I want to know where is the IP of the host. so I can't configure the registrar control panel to point to that IP.
So is there any way to know that IP, without configure the name server to point to it.
and I know the Name Server of the hosting. for example ns1.hosting.com

can I ask the specify ns1.hosting.com to get the IP of example.com

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are asking if you can find the name of a host on a specific name server?  On a *nix/OSX machine you can run `dig @ns1.hosting.com example.com a` in a terminal window.

On a Windows machine from the command prompt you can type `nslookup server ns1.hosting.com example.com`.

Or you can try an online tool like http://centralops.net/co/